# Confusing example of inheritance. Constructor is overriden but function is not. Why?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

You can see from the below example that I have two classes - one called Player and the other Computer. The Computer class is a child of Player.

I have instantiated both dynamically allocating memory with the 'new' keyword so as to be able to use them in different scopes - notice that the Computer-player is instantiated in an if statement block.

Strangely it compiles and player two is constructed using the Computer constructor, and yet when I call player2->takeTurn() method it is using the Player::takeTurn() method rather than Computer::takeTurn() ...

I can't understand why. You can probably tell from the language I use that I am a beginner at C++ and am more used to Java so perhaps am just not understanding how inheritance works in C++?

Stuff I tried:

My first thought was that it was because I was using a Player* pointer rather than a Computer* pointer (I don't see why that would be a problem but thought I would test) so I have tried recasting the pointer for player2 like this:

```
player2 = (Computer*) player2;
```

And this compiles and runs but has no effect on the output.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class Player {
private:
    string name;
    bool isTurn;
    bool isCrosses;

public:
    //constructor
    Player(string n = "") : name(n), isTurn(true), isCrosses(true) {}
    //getters
    string getName() {return name;}
    bool getIsTurn() {return isTurn;}
    bool getIsCrosses() {return isCrosses;}
    //setters
    void setName(string n) {name = n;}
    void setIsTurn(bool b) {isTurn = b;}
    void setIsCrosses(bool b) {isCrosses =b;}   
    //game functions
    int takeTurn() {
        cout << "Player " << name << " player taketurn function." << endl;      
        return 0;
    } 
};

class Computer : public Player {

public:
    Computer() : Player("Computer") {
        setIsCrosses(false);
        setIsTurn(false);
    }

    int takeTurn() {
        cout << "This is the computers taketurn function." << endl;

        return 0;
    }

};

int main() {


    //innit game variables
    bool playing = true;
    bool vsComp = true;

    Player* player1;
    Player* player2;

    player1 = new Player("aPlayer");

    if (vsComp) player2 = new Computer;




    //Gameloop  
    while (playing) {

        //draw board


        //take player input
        if (player1->getIsTurn()) {
            int cross = player1->takeTurn();    
            int naught = 0;

            player1->setIsTurn(false);
            player2->setIsTurn(true);

        } else {
            player2->takeTurn();

            player1->setIsTurn(true);
            player2->setIsTurn(false);
        }


        //update changes


    }


    //Clean up 
    delete player1;
    delete player2;

    player1 = 0;
    player2 = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`takeTurn` should be virtual function.
In base class put virtual before function definition:

```
virtual int takeTurn()
```

destructor of class `Player` also should be declared and should be `virtual`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answers above, I think it's worth pointing out that if you are using c++11 you can get the compiler to catch this error for you.

Simply mark any function that you think is an override of a base class's version with the specifier `override`

like this:

```
class Computer : public Player {

...
    int takeTurn() override // override specifier added
    {
        ...
    }
...
};
```

This has the effect of telling the compiler "I believe that this is an override of a virtual function - tell me if I am wrong".